# Geometric mean of affine matrices

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, matrices

Hi,

I'd like to compute the geometric mean of several affine transformations (e.g. represented by 4x4 affine matrices). Going a step back, what's the geometric mean of n 3x3 matrices (with det > 0, basically representing rotations,scaling, shearing but no flips or projections).

I have seen many definitions for pos def. matrices and some work on SO(3) but not for linear or affine transforms.

Comment: Going another step back, what does "geometric mean" mean for matrices?

Comment: Do these matrices live in a nice differentiable manifold?